# BigQuery API intermittently returns http error 404 Token Not Found on jobCollection.list_next(request, job_list)

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am building a python script to collect BigQuery usage statistics by end-user. As I loop through the list of jobs using:

next_request = jobCollection.list_next(request, job_list)
job_list = next_request.execute()

I am intermittently receiving a 404 error response from the call. This does not occur in the same place. Sometimes I can loop a dozen times, sometimes a hundred. But sooner or later I get an error response like:

Error: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/rising-ocean-426/jobs?alt=json&allUsers=true&projection=full&stateFilter=done&pageToken=1427701801169-job_kaAU3mjgVXIXVHfoolqI-_ORXG4 returned "Not Found: Token 1427701801169-job_kaAU3mjgVXIXVHfoolqI-_ORXG4"> encountered

The script is as follows:

```
import optparse
import os
import sys
import time

from google_services import get_service

# Parser for command-line arguments.
parser = optparse.OptionParser(usage=__doc__, version="%prog 1.0")

parser.disable_interspersed_args()
parser.add_option('--auth_host_name', default='localhost',
              help='Hostname when running a local web server.')
parser.add_option('--noauth_local_webserver', action='store_true',
              default=False, help='Do not run a local web server.')
parser.add_option('--auth_host_port', default=[8080, 8090], type=int,
              nargs='*', help='Port web server should listen on.')
parser.add_option('--logging_level', default='ERROR',
              choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR',
                       'CRITICAL'],
              help='Set the logging level of detail.')

"""
This program scans the jobs log to collect consumption information by         user id.
"""

def main():

    (flags,_args) = parser.parse_args()

    bq_service    = get_service('bigquery', 'v2', flags)
    jobCollection = bq_service.jobs()

    request = jobCollection.list(projectId='rising-ocean-    426',allUsers=True,projection='full',stateFilter='done')
job_list = request.execute()

done = False
user_statistics = {}
while not done and job_list is not None:
    for job in job_list['jobs'] :
        if 'configuration' not in job:
            continue
        if 'query' not in job['configuration']:
            continue
        if 'errorResult' in job:
            sys.stderr.write("Error Result encountered: \n%s\n" %     job['errorResult'])
            message  = job['errorResult']['message']
            reason   = job['errorResult']['reason']
            query    = job['configuration']['query']['query']
            sys.stderr.write("Error encountered: %s,    %s\nQuery:\n%s\n" % (message, reason, query))
            continue
        if 'statistics' not in job:
            continue
        if 'query' not in job['statistics']:
            continue
        if 'cacheHit' not in job['statistics']['query']:
            continue
        if job['statistics']['query']['cacheHit']:
            continue
        endTime = job['statistics']['endTime']
        endDate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',     time.localtime(long(endTime)/1000))
        if endDate >= '2015-04-01':
            continue
        if endDate < '2015-03-01':
            done = True
            break
        totalBytesProcessed = long(job['statistics']['query']    ['totalBytesProcessed'])
        query               = job['configuration']['query']['query']
        jobId               = job['jobReference']['jobId']
        email               = job['user_email']

        user_stat = user_statistics.get(email,{})
        user_statistics[email] = user_stat
        user_stat['totalBytesProcessed'] = user_stat.get('totalBytesProcessed', 0) + totalBytesProcessed
        query_statistics = user_stat.get('query_statistics',{})
        user_stat['query_statistics'] = query_statistics
        query_stat = query_statistics.get(query,{})
        query_statistics[query] = query_stat
        query_stat['totalBytesProcessed'] = query_stat.get('totalBytesProcessed', 0) + totalBytesProcessed
        job_statistics = query_stat.get('job_statistics',{})
        query_stat['job_statistics'] = job_statistics
        job_statistics[jobId] = totalBytesProcessed
    if done :
        break
    try:
        sys.stderr.write("Requesting Next Page. EndDate:%s, nextPageToken:%s\n" % (endDate, job_list['nextPageToken']))
        next_request = jobCollection.list_next(request, job_list)
        job_list = next_request.execute()
    except Exception, e :
        sys.stderr.write("Error: %s encountered\n" % e,)
        done = True
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    sys.stderr.write("update_big_query_job_status is exiting\n")
```

I've found a work-around to the problem that involves creating a different nextPage token using the penultimate job on the returned list. Naturally, this means that the last job is repeated and needs special handling. Nevertheless, this shows that the problem is that the Bigquery jobs.list_next is rejecting a nextPage token that it, itself, returned. Anyway, the work-around is as follows:

```
jobCollection = bq_service.jobs()

maxResults = 10000

request = jobCollection.list(projectId='rising-ocean-426', allUsers=True,projection='full', maxResults=maxResults)
job_list = request.execute()

while job_list is not None:
    sys.stderr.write("Processed %s jobs\n" % len(job_list['jobs']))
    last_job = job_list['jobs'][-1]
    job_id  = last_job['jobReference']['jobId']
    endTime = last_job['statistics']['endTime']
    endDate = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(long(endTime)/1000))
    if endDate < '2015-01_01' :
        break
    try:
        last_page_token = job_list['nextPageToken']
        sys.stderr.write("Requesting Next Page. EndDate:%s, nextPageToken:%s\n" % (endDate, job_list['nextPageToken']))
        next_request = jobCollection.list_next(request, job_list)
        job_list = next_request.execute()
        request = next_request
    except Exception, e :
        sys.stderr.write("Error: %s encountered\n" % e,)
        last_good_page_token = job_list['jobs'][-2]['statistics']['creationTime'] + '-' + job_list['jobs'][-2]['jobReference']['jobId']
        request = jobCollection.list(projectId='rising-ocean-426',allUsers=True,projection='full', pageToken=last_good_page_token, maxResults=maxResults)
        job_list = request.execute()
        continue
```

It looks as if there are certain jobs that jobCollection.list(...) and jobCollection.list_next(...) are not able to retrieve, even though jobCollection.get(...) can find them.

Edited to add: There was an error in the original code as well as the work-around, wherein the request was not updated in the call to list_next. I made the modification in hopes that that was the root of the problem. Unfortunately, that is not the case, the list_next call still fails intermittently, so the work-around is still necessary.

Comment: It appears that a critical factor in causing this error is the stateFilter='done' flag in the call to jobCollection.list; If I remove the stateFilter flag, the subsequent call to  jobCollection.list_next() appears to work, or at least to fail less frequently.

Comment: I have managed to hop-scotch my way through the 404 errors by keeping track of the last good nextPageToken and reissuing the jobCollection.list call with the last good token and reducing the maxResults parameter to the size of the job_list['jobs'] -5 so that the resulting jobs_list returns with a different (valid) token. I then resume from that point.